# OpenOffice add entry in one index and not in another

Tags: indexing, openoffice-writer

There are two indexes in an OpenOffice document (Writter): one is for all contents and another is for only tables of document.

When I added an entry in an Index (e.g. Revision History which is above main Index) with these steps:

1. Select heading, which we want to add in the Index
2. Menu > Insert
3. Indexes and Tables > Entry
4. Select "Table of Contents" from Index dropdown menu and Insert

After that, if I update both Indexes, the entry is added to both Indexes. I don't want that entry in Index of tables but only in Index of main content.

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way for now. As the topic was above the main Content Index which I wanted to exclude from one Index, I followed these steps:

1. Right click on Index of Tables
2. Edit Index/Table
3. Create index/table for Chapter (instead of Entire Document)